# What is the square root of a negative number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For $ x^2+1=0 $ , can we say that:
$ x=+i $ and $ x=-i $

Comment: Yes, and this question has been asked for many times

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: For $x^2+1=0$ we can say that $x=+i$ is a solution and we can say that $x=-i$ is a solution.  Alternatively, given that $x^2+1=0$ we can say that $x=i$ or $x=-i$.  What we cannot say is given that $x^2+1=0$ that $x=i$ *and* $x=-i$ as that would imply that a single value of $x$ is simultaneously equal to two different nonequal values.

Comment: Well, no, to be strictly accurate. Maybe you meant $x=i$ OR $-i$. But don't worry too much no-one can tell them apart! After all how do you know which is which?

Comment: @almagest:  couldn't you distinguish by saying that multiplication by $i$ corresponds to $90^o$ counterclockwise rotation in the complex plane, whereas multiplication by $-i$ corresponds to $90^o$ clockwise rotation?

Comment: x=i is the only solution stated

Comment: @J.W.Tanner that begs the question as to how we set up the "complex plane" in the first place, why we chose up and down/clockwise counterclockwise.  We can't avoid that it *was* arbitrary.

Comment: @J.W. Tanner, while counterclockwise is well defined (positivity is well defined and 1 is also well defined hence the real coordinate too, hence the purely complex one), complex multiplication is defined in terms of $i$ so we go circular, in other words, $i$ is the one with argument $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but we have an isomorphism over $\mathbb R$ that sends it to $-i$ etc

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Why only +i is the only solution given but not - i

Comment: @EnockKabibi "x=i is the only solution stated".  Stated where?  If it stated that $x^2 +1 = 0$ had only one solution or that $x=i$ or $x = -i$ were two solutions, then it is just plain wrong.  ... And it's important to realize that the statement i)$x^2 - a =0$ and ii) $x =\sqrt a$ are *NOT* equivalent.... and that no matter *how* you define what $\sqrt{a}$ means, it conventionally means that $\sqrt{a}$ is *ONE* of two possible solutions to $x^2 -a = 0$.

Comment: "Why only +i is the only solution given but not - i "  Because your text is effing WRONG.

Comment: "Why only +i is the only solution given but not - i".  Given by whom under what circumstance? If someone casually said "the solution to $x^2 + 1=0$ is $i$" they may have been too casual.  If you paid \$200 for a text that says "$x^2+1=0$ has $i$ as it's only solution" then you were badly cheated.

Comment: I've never seen that anywhere but I hope I should just read more of this. Thanks for your kind thoughts

Comment: Bottom line:  $i$ is a complex number.  $i^2=-1$.  All complex numbers are of the form $a + bi$ where $a,b\in \mathbb R$.  From that, basic algebra will yield that the equation $x^2 + 1 =0$ will have two solutions.  One is $i$ and the other is $-i$.

Comment: People need to be careful.  If you are trying to define what $i$ is by saying it is a solution to $x^2 + 1=0$, you should be careful to say that $i$ is *A* solution.